# Is correlation (in some sense) transitive?

Tags: probability, correlation

If we know that A has some correlation with B ($\rho_{AB}$), and that B has some with C ($\rho_{BC}$), is there something we know to say about the correlation between A and C ($\rho_{AC}$)?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really. Take two iid $A,C$, then $B=A+C$ is correlated to both $A$ and $C$, but $X$ and $Y$ are independent. On the other hand, if $A=B=C$, then they are all very correlated to each other.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Correlations are cosines of angles in $L^2$ hence, if $\varrho_{AB}\geqslant 0$ and $\varrho_{BC}\geqslant 0$, then
$$
\varrho_{AC}\geqslant\varrho_{AB}\varrho_{BC}-\sqrt{1-\varrho_{AB}^2}\cdot\sqrt{1-\varrho_{BC}^2}.
$$
Thus, if $\varrho_{AB}\geqslant c$ and $\varrho_{BC}\geqslant c$ with $c\geqslant0$, then
$$
\varrho_{AC}\geqslant2c^2-1.
$$
For example, if $\varrho_{AB}\geqslant90\%$ and $\varrho_{BC}\geqslant90\%$ then $\varrho_{AC}\geqslant62\%$.

Comment: Nice precise version of the intuitive notion that there is a (partial) connection.

Comment: Great answer Did. What are the names of the inequality you are using? (I apologies for my ignorance)

Comment: @TalGalili You noted that this is just the formula for the addition of angles $\cos(u+v)=\cos(u)\cos(v)-\sin(u)\sin(v)$, plus the realization that the angle between A and C is *at most* the sum of those between A and B and between B and C.

Comment: @Did, just wondering how did you derive that formula in the first line

Comment: @wrek Please see comment Dec 14 '13 at 7:17.

Comment: Dear Did, Thanks for your reply. I don't understand how can you relate angle (cosine) to the correlation...

Comment: @wrek This is stated explicitely in the first sentence of the answer and is due to the fact that the mapping $L^2\times L^2\to\mathbb R$, $(X,Y)\mapsto\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$ is a scalar product.

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid this is a non-answer: probably.

But imagine tossing a fair coin $100$ times. Let $A$ be the number of heads in the first $50$ tosses, $B$ the number of heads in the full $100$ tosses, and $C$ the number of heads in the last $50$ tosses.

Then $A$ and $B$ are (weakly) positively correlated, as are $B$ and $C$, but $A$ and $C$ have correlation $0$.

By working a little harder, we could even get negative correlation between $A$ and $C$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small ($2$ instead of $100$) version of André's answer, so as to make correlations easier to compute.  Flip two coins.  Let $A$ be $1$ if the first coin comes up heads, and $0$ if tails. Define $C$ similarly using the second coin.  Let $B$ be $1$ if both coins come up heads, and $0$ otherwise.