# Do angle properties (e.g. interior angles of a triangle sum to $\pi$) hold in general inner product spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, angle

I've been rediscovering inner product spaces recently and have developed a couple of questions about angles defined in general inner product spaces.

Consider the real vector space $V$ equipped with inner product $\langle \dot{},\dot{}\rangle : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ .

Take $X,Y,Z\in V$. Define the angle between $X$ and $Z$ as
$$\theta_{XZ} := \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\langle{}X,Z\rangle{}}{||X|| \dot{}||Z||}\right)$$
and define $\theta_{XY}$ and $\theta_{YZ}$ similarly. Then is it possible to prove that:

(i) (a sort of triangle inequality)
$$\theta_{XZ} \leq \theta_{XY} + \theta_{YZ}$$

(ii) in the case where $Z=Y-X$,  $$\theta_{XY}+\theta_{YZ}+\theta_{XZ}=\pi$$
(i.e. the interior angles of a triangle sum to $\pi$)?

In the case $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, these results are known to secondary school children! Are they true in any real inner product space?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever heard about obtuse triangles? i) does not hold for them.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the definition. Treating $X,Y,Z$ as corners of a triangle and $\theta_{XY}$ as the angle at $Z$ subtended by $XY$, then you're correct, (i) does not hold. But $X,Y,Z$ are elements of $V$ here, not points. Try sketching three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and label the acute/obtuse angles between them to convince yourself.

Comment: I'm less convinced about (ii), actually. Sketching the setup in $\mathbb{R}^2$ shows $\theta_{YZ}$ to be an exterior angle of the triangle. We might need to use $\hat{\theta}_{YZ} := \pi - \theta_{YZ}$ in place of $\theta_{YZ}$ for (ii) to hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements (i) and (ii) are unchanged if we replace $V$ with the subspace spanned by $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. So for (i) we may assume $V$ is $3$-dimensional, and for (ii) we may assume $V$ is $2$-dimensional. Every finite-dimensional real inner product space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the usual dot product) for some $n$, so without loss of generality we may assume $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ in (i) and $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ in (ii).

As you say, with a slight modification, (ii) is known to secondary school children. The statement should be
$$
\theta_{XY} +\theta_{(-Y)(-Z)} + \theta_{(-X)Z} = \pi,
$$
which is equivalent to the modification you suggest in the comments.

Statement (i) is invariant under scaling, so we may assume $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The angle between two unit vectors is the same as the great circle distance between the corresponding points on the unit sphere, so (i) follows from the well-known fact that the shortest path between two points on a sphere is a great circle.

Comment: That's beautiful Julian, thanks a lot!

My question was motivated by trying to bound $corr(X,Z)$ ($X$ and $Z$ being second-integrable random variables) given $corr(X,Y)$ and $corr(Y,Z)$. I came upon [Tal Galili](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1406/tal-galili)'s question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/605967/252414); [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) provided a nice solution in which they assumed claim (i). I love how this problem concerning random variables has been reduced to a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$!

Comment: Hi @Julian Rosen Can you please explain me what is the meaning of the subscripts $(-Y)(-Z)$ and $(-X)Z$ in the modified equation? Is $-Y$ the additive inverse of $Y$?

Comment: Yes, $-Y$ is the additive inverse of $Y$. By $\theta_{(-Y)(-Z)}$, I mean the angle between the vectors $-Y$ and $-Z$ (using OP's definition of angle).